# When precisely will security support for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS end?

Tags: updates, security, ubuntu-gnome

Security support for Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS is supposed to end in April 2019, that is, this month. However, I couldn’t find any information regarding when exactly in April this will happen. On what *day* will the security support end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

30-April-2019 for all GNOME related GUI parts, plus anything else from the 'universe' (or community-supported) repository.

End of April 2021 for all 'main' repository software, which includes kernel & some programs provided in Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04.

For more information on your actual install, please use `ubuntu-support-status`